# How to add these queries together (Yii2)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, api, yii2

I've made an API in Yii2 with the following to queries:

```
public function actionGetcarinfo($ac, $id){
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $rows = (new Query())
        ->select(['a.auto_id', 'm.merk', 'a.model', 'a.uitvoering', 'k.kleur', 't.transmissie', 'a.kmstand', 'a.bouwjaar', 'a.vermogen', 'b.brandstof', 'g.garantie', 'a.prijs'])
        ->from('auto_new a')
        ->where(['a.ac' => $ac, 'a.auto_id' => $id])
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_merken m', 'a.merk = m.merk_id')
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_kleur k', 'a.kleur = k.kleur_id')
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_transmissie t', 'a.transmissie = t.transmissie_id')
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_brandstof b', 'a.brandstof = b.brandstof_id')
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_garantie g', 'a.garantie = g.garantie_id')
        ->all();
    return $rows;
}
```

[image]

And this:

```
public function actionGetcaroptions($ac, $id){
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $rows = (new Query())
        ->select(['atn.NL'])
        ->from('auto_new a')
        ->where(['a.ac' => $ac, 'a.auto_id' => $id])
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'auto_accessoire acc', 'a.auto_id = acc.auto_id AND a.ac = acc.ac')
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'tbl_accessoires_trader_new atn', 'acc.code_id = atn.code_id')
        ->all();
    return $rows;
}
```

[image]

Now I want to add this list with options to the query above. So the json wil get something like: options: list with options.

I don't know how to add these two queries together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain old sql your queries are:

```
select a.auto_id, m.merk, a.model, a.uitvoering, k.kleur, t.transmissie, a.kmstand, a.bouwjaar, a.vermogen, b.brandstof, g.garantie, a.prijs
from auto_new a
INNER JOIN tbl_merken m on a.merk = m.merk_id
INNER JOIN tbl_kleur k on a.kleur = k.kleur_id
INNER JOIN tbl_transmissie t on a.transmissie = t.transmissie_id
INNER JOIN tbl_brandstof b on a.brandstof = b.brandstof_id
INNER JOIN tbl_garantie g on a.garantie = g.garantie_id
WHERE a.ac = ? and a.auto_id = ?

select atn.NL
from auto_new a
INNER JOIN auto_accessoire acc on a.auto_id = acc.auto_id AND a.ac = acc.ac
INNER JOIN tbl_accessoires_trader_new atn on acc.code_id = atn.code_id
WHERE a.ac = ? and a.auto_id = ?
```

combining these

```
select a.auto_id, m.merk, a.model, a.uitvoering, k.kleur, t.transmissie, a.kmstand, a.bouwjaar, a.vermogen, b.brandstof, g.garantie, a.prijs,
group_concat(atn.NL) as options_list
from auto_new a
INNER JOIN tbl_merken m on a.merk = m.merk_id
INNER JOIN tbl_kleur k on a.kleur = k.kleur_id
INNER JOIN tbl_transmissie t on a.transmissie = t.transmissie_id
INNER JOIN tbl_brandstof b on a.brandstof = b.brandstof_id
INNER JOIN tbl_garantie g on a.garantie = g.garantie_id
INNER JOIN auto_accessoire acc on a.auto_id = acc.auto_id AND a.ac = acc.ac
INNER JOIN tbl_accessoires_trader_new atn on acc.code_id = atn.code_id
WHERE a.ac = ? and a.auto_id = ?
group by a.auto_id, m.merk, a.model, a.uitvoering, k.kleur, t.transmissie, a.kmstand, a.bouwjaar, a.vermogen, b.brandstof, g.garantie, a.prijs
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html for more information. The logic is just add the two queries together with joins then take the rows of options and make them into a string (so you have one row of all the options per a.ac and a.auto_id). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I want :)

Comment: There is still a little problem. When I try to get all photo's this way it works. But some cars don't have photo's. So when they don't have any I get no info at all. http://pastebin.com/4X80e9VP

Comment: Change the join(s) to photo table(s) from inner to left and it should solve your problem. I don't speak Dutch so it's hard for me to tell which ones those might be but my guess is one of or both of the last two joins.

Comment: Thanks thats it indeed.